# VBA doing random calculations and confirming right answer

Tags: vba, calculation, msgbox

Below code gives you a random calculation, you provide an answer and programme check if your answer was correct or not. Over all you get 5 examples to solve. At the end I would like to create a simple MsgBox stating in how many instances the user was right - Amount of correct answers.

This MsgBox is currently represented by "g". Unfortunately g = b + 0 in combination with g = b - 1 is not the correct way to go.

Can anybody help? Thank you!

```
Sub Main2()

Dim b, e, f, s1, s2 As Byte
Dim g As String

    g = 0
    For b = 1 To 5

    e = Round(Rnd() * 10)
    f = Round(Rnd() * 10)
        MsgBox ("Count: ") & Str(e) & (" *") & Str(f)
    s1 = InputBox("What's the result?")

    s2 = e * f
    If s1 = s2 Then
        MsgBox ("Correct")
        g = b + 0

    Else
        MsgBox ("Incorrect! Right answer is") & Str(s2)
        g = b - 1

        End If

    Next b

    MsgBox ("Amount of correct answers: ") & Str(g)

End Sub
```

Comment: Surely it is `g=g+1` for a correct and `g=g-1` for a wrong answer or am I missing something? You might also want `RANDOMIZE TIMER` to randomize each run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
g = g + 1
```

For correct and remove the `g = b - 1` from the wrong as you do not want to increase g at all.

Also you need to dim `g` as a number not a string

```
Dim g as Long
```

And

> `Dim b, e, f, s1, s2 As Byte`

only will declare `s2` as a `Byte` the others will be `Variant`.

Use:

```
Dim b As Byte, e As Byte, f As Byte, s1 As Byte, s2 As Byte
```

---

```
Sub Main2()

    Dim b As Byte, e As Byte, f As Byte, s1 As Byte, s2 As Byte
    Dim g As Long

    g = 0
    For b = 1 To 5

        e = Round(Rnd() * 10)
        f = Round(Rnd() * 10)
        MsgBox ("Count: ") & cStr(e) & (" * ") & cStr(f)
        s1 = InputBox("What's the result?")

        s2 = e * f

        If s1 = s2 Then
            MsgBox ("Correct")
            g = g + 1    
        Else
            MsgBox ("Incorrect! Right answer is") & cStr(s2)
        End If

    Next b

    MsgBox ("Amount of correct answers: ") & cStr(g)

End Sub
```